# Jquery Chat with angularjs binding as username

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am using a hand jquery plugin created by [Anant Garg](http://anantgarg.com/2009/05/13/gmail-facebook-style-jquery-chat/) and to start a chat you must call the chatWith function like this `onclick="chatWith('test')"` where test is the username you want to open a chat with.

I am using angularjs for the rest of my site and attempted to call the above function like so

```
<a class="aclass" id="userChange" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="chatWith('{{Users.User}}')">{{Users.User}}</a>
```

but that does not work and the solution would be to use ng-click but than the chatWith function does not get called on click? Is there a angular way to do this? thanks for any input

Comment: Place chatWith function in the controller scope of the chat. most likely where you have the user list defined.

Comment: @Geohut chatWith comes along with the plugin and is a jquery function is that possible ?

Comment: If you wrap a jquery plugin as a directive and then use it within the score of your controller it is possible:
https://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/an-approach-to-use-jquery-plugins-with-angularjs/

Comment: @Kepoly I looked at chat.js code you referred to. It is 6 years old JS code which is not up to the standards of today's JS code. For example - chat.js has global functions which is against angular principle. Having said that, it should still work if you call `chatWith` from the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call jquery plugin function in controller

First you must import jquery and plugin to your index.html before import your controller.
Then in your controller, declare a function:

```
$scope.chat = function(username){
    //call jquery plugin function
    chatWith(username);
}
```

In your view

```
<a class="aclass" id="userChange" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="chat(Users.User)">{{Users.User}}</a>
```